# remove IIS 7 redirects

Tags: .net, iis-7, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to debug an IIS server that keeps redirecting *.html files to *.aspx...

it sends the following html in response to url.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>website title redirected</title>
    <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=url.aspx"> 
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Where can i find the rules that dictate this?

Answer (score -1):

Open IIS, look at properties for default website and look at document types (tab I think). There should be a list of default pages (i.e. default.html, default.aspx, etc.) If not there then there is a redirect option in the properties for each site. Check that and make sure its not redirecting from there.